# Stable and reliable JIRA plugin for Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

Can anyone suggest reliable JIRA plugin for Jenkins pls? We had integrated by its not creating issues on every failure. Which we expect Jenkins to create JIRA issue on every failure.

any link, document pls

Comment: Why not asking the author of the plugin to add such a functionality?

Comment: Sorry, that's not what SO is for.